# Twilio - determine if a number is already in a call before initiating

Tags: twilio

I have a somewhat peculiar situation for which I can't find documentation: I have an application that will use the Twilio API to initiate a voice call from phone number X (my number) to another one. The problem is that number X could already be in the middle of another call, one that was not initiated with Twilio (so my application wouldn't know about it). Would Twilio detect this, and send an error, or try to initiate the call anyway? If the former, what would the error be? I have found the error code for "callee busy", but nothing similar to "caller busy".

Alternatively, is there an API call I could make before initiating the call to make sure number X is available and not in another call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio numbers can have multiple calls associated with them, so there would be no error id the Phone X was on an existing call (since phone numbers can be routed however you choose). You can set the outbound CallerID to be another Twilio number or a verified callerID (but if they call that verified callerID back, it wont go back to Twilio but the carrier/business owning that number).

Once the dialed party answers after making the outbound API call, you tell Twilio how to route the other piece (who to connect the answering party to) via the URL parameter hosting the Twilio Markup Language (TwiML).

There is an API call and example for, [Read multiple Call resources and filter by call status and phone number (Code Example)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource), you could query before making your outbound call (assuming you always map inbound calls to the same endpoint) or routing your inbound call (which probably makes more sense if you want to re-route to another destination who can answer the call).

The status of this call. Can be: queued, ringing, in-progress, canceled, completed, failed, busy or no-answer.